# TypeError: _initFirebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.firebase.database is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to push new data to my `Firebase Realtime Database`.

I have this `initFirebase.js`:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/database'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBhiHbrO2qUvGDmGN3iX5u-SlpRK_EPlzU",
    authDomain: "table-app-e64c3.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "table-app-e64c3",
    storageBucket: "table-app-e64c3.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "102169979497",
    appId: "1:102169979497:web:c8dc8170bd6ce50f4850f8",
    measurementId: "G-6RC7ZQ1177"
  };

  function initFirebase() {
      if (!firebase.getApps.length){
          firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
      }
  }
  
  initFirebase()

  export { firebase }
```

And I have this `App.js` (I pasted the only part that is relevant):

```
import { firebase } from "./initFirebase"
const App = () => {
//...

  const handleAddFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    
    const listRef = firebase.database().ref("Lists")
    const newListRef = listRef.push()
    newListRef.set({
        //Some Data to insert
      })
  }

//...
}

export default App;
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: _initFirebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.firebase.database is not a function

handleAddFormSubmit

  43 |    setContacts(newContacts)
  44 | 
  45 |    //Represent a new record in the database
> 46 |    const listRef = firebase.database().ref("Lists")
     | ^  47 |    const newListRef = listRef.push()
  48 |    newListRef.set({
```

Everything breaks in the above function that I've pasted `handleAddFormSubmit` & I fail again and again to solve this problem. I'm new with React & Firebase and I'll Appreciate any help or direction to the solution. Thanks.

Solved, Edit:
Full documentation of `Modular SDK (v9)` (with comparison to v8) [can be found here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have the new Modular SDK (v9) installed which does not have the `firebase.database()` syntax but uses a new syntax. If you want to keep rest of the code as it is, then change your imports to compat libraries:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/auth'
import 'firebase/compat/database'
```

I'd recommend using the new Modular syntax as it has benefits of tree-shaking. You can try refactoring your code to this:

```
import { initializeApp } form "firebase/app"
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database"

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const auth = getAuth(app)
const db = getDatabase(app)

export { auth, db }
```

Then in `app.js`:

```
import { auth, db } from "./initFirebase"
import { ref, push, set } from "firebase/database"

const handleAddFormSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
    
  const listRef = ref(db, 'Lists');
  const newItemRef = push(listRef);
  set(newPostRef, {..data});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution!
Works perfectly well :)!